# Reading single record, splitting to multiple observations but retaining one value

Tags: sas

I am having billing data for a customer during the last 12 months in a single record. The customer ID is a 6 digit number.

```
108263 $946.00 $903.00 $804.00 $674.00 $663.00 $195.00 $922.00 $595.00
> $157.00 $415.00 $868.00 $750.00
```

I need to break the data into the below format. Note, I would also have to display the months (month number & month name), which needs to be computed automatically.

```
Cust_ID | Month.N | Month.W|Bill Amt
108263|1|Jan|$946.00
108263|2|Feb|$903.00
...
108263|12|Dec|$750.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data have;
input Cust_ID $ @@;
do i=1 to 12;
   Month_N=i;
   Month_W=substr(put(intnx('month','01Jan2018'd,i-1),Date9.),3,3);
   input Bill_Amt $ @@;
   output;
end;
drop i;
cards; 
108263 $946.00 $903.00 $804.00 $674.00 $663.00 $195.00 $922.00 $595.00 $157.00 $415.00 $868.00 $750.00
;
```

Answer (score 0):

if data is in SAS dataset then one way to do this

```
data want;
set have;
cust_id =scan(text,1,' ');
do i = 2 to 13;
month_n = i -1;
if month_n = 1 then month_w = 'Jan';
if month_n = 2 then month_w = 'Feb';
if month_n = 3 then month_w = 'Mar';
if month_n = 4 then month_w = 'Apr';
if month_n = 5 then month_w = 'May';
if month_n = 6 then month_w = 'Jun';
if month_n = 7 then month_w = 'Jul';
if month_n = 8 then month_w= 'Aug';
if month_n = 9 then month_w = 'Sep';
if month_n = 10 then month_w = 'Oct';
if month_n = 11 then month_w = 'Nov';
if month_n = 12 then month_w = 'Dec';
billamount = input(scan(text, i, ' '),  COMMA10.2);
output;
end;
drop i text;
format billamount dollar10.2;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading data from a text file the informat `NLMNLUSDw.d` can parse currency values.

Create example text file to read from

```
filename have temp;

data _null_;
  file have;
  put "108263 $946.00 $903.00 $804.00 $674.00 $663.00 $195.00 $922.00 $595.00 $157.00 $415.00 $868.00 $750.00";
  put "108264 $946.00 $903.00 $804.00 $674.00 $663.00 $195.00 $922.00 $595.00 $157.00 $415.00 $868.00 $750.00";
  put "108265 $946.00 $903.00 $804.00 $674.00 $663.00 $195.00 $922.00 $595.00"; * some missing months;
run;
```

Example:

`NLMNLUSDw.d` Informat Reads the monetary format of the local expression for Puerto Rico, and the United States.  The `input` statement here works best when the variable attributes are specified prior to the statement.

```
data want;
  infile have missover;
  attrib
    id length=8 
    month_num length=8 
    month_name3 length=$3 
    amount length=8 informat=NLMNLUSD9.2 format=DOLLAR9.2
  ;
  input id @;
  do month_num = 1 to 12;  * presume each row has 12 months of data;
    month_name3 = put(mdy(month_num,1,2000), monname3.);
    input amount @;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Note that `COMMA.` informat can read values with `$` and `,` embedded in them.